# How do you rebuild nixos packages using cloned nixpkgs?

Tags: nixos

I really like the deterministic nature of nixos/nix, but I'm having trouble understanding the best way to customize packages for my use.  I have had limited success using the `nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides` attribute but it's painful and I find that it fails more often than it works (e.g. I spent weeks trying to override the version of virtualbox that I was picking up in the stable and unstable channels but it never worked correctly).

My next attempt was to clone the nixpkgs repository and try to modify the expressions directly.  I thought this would work if I added the path of my clone to the beginning of `$NIX_PATH`.  However, rebuilding doesn't seem to pick up my changes.  I also tried the `nixos-rebuild -I $NIXPKGS switch` variant as described at https://nixos.org/wiki/Create_and_debug_nix_packages, but it doesn't pick up my changes either.

Is this cloning approach possible and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VirtualBox is special because it's not a simple package, but also requires NixOS integration (setuid). So it's really best to clone nixpkgs to modify it.

`nixos-rebuild switch -I /mypath` should work, where nixpkgs is located inside `/mypath`.

Comment: It's finally working.  I think what I did wrong was I included "nixpkgs" in the path I was using (e.g. export NIXPKGS=/home/userid/nixpkgs).  Leaving "nixpkgs" out of the path fixed things.